# Graphics2D - Rotating Shapes on a Graphics2D object

Tags: java, swing, graphics2d

I have a `Graphics2D` object which I use to draw on my `Canvas`. I draw multiple shapes on the `Canvas` and want to transform only one (or part) of them.

I'll try to keep this simple:

```
void render(Graphics2D g) {
    ... // Draw shape 1
    ... // Draw shape 2
    ... // Draw shape 3
}
```

**How would I go about rotating shape 2 while leaving shape 1 and 3 intact?** By "rotate" I mean rotating around its center point, which we can define as `x` and `y` for example.

I've been looking for a way to do this for a while now, but couldn't find anything that works the way I want it to.

Is there any simple way to do this?

Comment: *"couldn't find anything that works the way I want it to"*  Can you show an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) of your best attempt?  Describe in what way the transform does not meet your expectations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than rotating the shape around it's centre point, rotate and then translate the canvas. To rotate around the centre of the shape at `(x, y)`, first translate the canvas by `(-x, -y)` and then rotate the canvas `-d` degrees and draw the shape as normal at (0,0).

When you're done, rotate back then translate back (note that with these geometric transformations the order is important, translating and then rotating will give you a completely different outcome).

This means that you can still draw an object at any rotation without having to recalculate the coordinates yourself.

Comment: I did change this up a bit to look like this: 1) `g.translate(x, y)` 2) `g.rotate(d)` 3) draw shape with center at (0, 0) 4) `g.rotate(-d)` 5) `g.translate(-x, -y)`. This works exactly the way I want. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
    AffineTransform afx = new AffineTransform();
    afx.rotate(angleRad, s.getCenter().x, s.getCenter().y);
    //afx.rotate(angleRad);
    java.awt.Shape ss = afx.createTransformedShape(s.getPrimativeShape());
    return ss;
```

`s` is my wrapper class for java.awt.Shape and does some stuff with it.... But what you want is in line 2.
`afx.rotate(`Angle`,`xAnchorPoint`,yAnchorPoint);`
afx.rotate rotates the object about the point (xAnchorPoint;yAnchorPoint).

Hope this is what you wanted

Answer (score 2):

In order to rotate a shape, use one of the `Graphics2D.rotate` methods.

Cache the transform used for both `shape 1` and `shape 3`. Before drawing `shape 3`, ensure that you reset the transform to the cached one, since using `rotate` for `shape 2` will alter the current transform coordinates.

Steps:

1. Cache current transform
2. Draw `shape 1`
3. Rotate
4. Draw `shape 2`
5. Set transform to cached one
6. Draw `shape 3`

Comment: This does work in that it rotates the shape, but it doesn't stay at the same place.