# Drawing antialiased shapes and rotating them in Java

Tags: java, java-7

**Background**

Im total Java newbie, today I started learning it (with [thenewboston.org](http://thenewboston.org)). I already know how to make simple windows/forms/gui, how to draw lines etc.

My goal is to create in Java gauge like this:

[image]

This is gauge which I created in .NET C# WPF, and now I want to rewrite this to Java.

**Main question**:

How to create triangle or other shape with some transparency and rotate it?

I tried to draw something by using Graphics object like this:

```
public void paint(Graphics g){
   g.drawLine(0, 0, 100, 100);
}
```

But I think this is wrong direction, because when I put something on graphics - it just stays there, I can't move or rotate it.

I have to clear whole graphics and draw it again to make kind of "animation", or there is easier way?

---

Edit:
I already know how to antialias ([Hovercraft Full Of Eels](https://stackoverflow.com/users/522444/hovercraft-full-of-eels) already helped me in this - thanks).

---

Edit2:

My code actually looks like this:

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MainWindow extends JPanel {

    private Point p1 = new Point(100, 100);
    private Point p2 = new Point(740, 450);

    public MainWindow() {
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        super.paintComponent(g);
        drawLines(g);
    }

    private void drawLines(Graphics g)
    {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        g2d.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);     
        g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(4, BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND, BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND));

        g.drawLine(p1.x, p1.y, p2.x, p2.y);

    }

    private void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Main Window");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(this);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new MainWindow().display();
    }

}
```

Comment: Might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8313526/graphics2d-rotating-shapes-on-a-graphics2d-object

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You state:

> I tried to draw something by using Graphics object like this:
>
> ```
> public void paint(Graphics g){
>    g.drawLine(0, 0, 100, 100);
> }
> ```
>
> But I think this is wrong direction, because when I put something on graphics - it just stays there, I can't move or rotate it.
>
> I have to clear whole graphics and draw it again to make kind of "animation", or there is easier way?

Suggestions:

- Don't hard-code your numbers. Use class fields (variables) instead so that your program can change the position of items drawn easily.
- Don't override a component's `paint(...)` method. Instead override the `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method of an object that derives from JComponent or one of its children such as JPanel. This will give you the benefit of automatic double-buffering for smoother animation, and also will reduce the likelihood of erroneous drawing of a component's children or borders.
- Cast your Graphics object to a Graphics2D object so that you can do more advanced drawing using classes that implement the Shape interface, including Rectangle2D, Ellipse2D, Line2D, Path2D, and many more.
- Draw the background image as a BufferedImage using `Graphics#drawImage(...)` method, and then draw your moving images on top of this, again using the Graphics2D object and again changing the images drawn based on the state of the object (the values held by its fields).
- Be careful when doing animations that you obey Swing threading rules, that you don't have any animation or game loops that tie up the Swing thread. A Swing Timer can allow you to create a quick and easy (albeit somewhat primitive) game loop.

For example:

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Stroke;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.*;

public class DailAnimation extends JPanel {
   private static final int PREF_W = 400;
   private static final int PREF_H = 350;
   private static final Point2D CENTER = new Point2D.Double(PREF_W / 2.0,
         PREF_W / 2.0);
   private static final double RADIUS = PREF_W / 2.0;
   private static final Color LARGE_TICK_COLOR = Color.green;
   private static final Color CENTER_HUB_COLOR = Color.LIGHT_GRAY;
   private static final Stroke LARGE_TICK_STROKE = new BasicStroke(3f);
   private static final int LRG_TICK_COUNT = 9;
   private static final double TOTAL_LRG_TICKS = 12;
   private static final double LRG_TICK_OUTER_RAD = 0.9;
   private static final double LRG_TICK_INNER_RAD = 0.8;
   private static final int START_TICK = 10;
   private static final double CENTER_HUB_RADIUS = 10;
   public static final int MAX_SPEED = 100;
   private static final double INIT_SPEED = 0;
   private static final double DIAL_INNER_RAD = 0.02;
   private static final double DIAL_OUTER_RAD = 0.75;
   private static final Color DIAL_COLOR = Color.DARK_GRAY;
   private BufferedImage backgroundImg;

   private double speed;
   private double theta;
   private double cosTheta;
   private double sinTheta;

   public DailAnimation() {
      setBackground(Color.white);

      backgroundImg = createBackgroundImg();
      setSpeed(INIT_SPEED);
   }

   public void setSpeed(double speed) {
      if (speed < 0) {
         speed = 0;
      } else if (speed > MAX_SPEED) {
         speed = MAX_SPEED;
      }
      this.speed = speed;
      this.theta = ((speed / MAX_SPEED) * LRG_TICK_COUNT * 2.0 + START_TICK)
            * Math.PI / TOTAL_LRG_TICKS;
      cosTheta = Math.cos(theta);
      sinTheta = Math.sin(theta);

      repaint();
   }

   private BufferedImage createBackgroundImg() {
      BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(PREF_W, PREF_H,
            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
      Graphics2D g2 = img.createGraphics();

      g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
      g2.setColor(LARGE_TICK_COLOR);
      g2.setStroke(LARGE_TICK_STROKE);

      for (int i = 0; i < LRG_TICK_COUNT; i++) {
         double theta = (i * 2.0 + START_TICK) * Math.PI / TOTAL_LRG_TICKS;
         double cosTheta = Math.cos(theta);
         double sinTheta = Math.sin(theta);

         int x1 = (int) (LRG_TICK_INNER_RAD * RADIUS * cosTheta + CENTER.getX());
         int y1 = (int) (LRG_TICK_INNER_RAD * RADIUS * sinTheta + CENTER.getY());
         int x2 = (int) (LRG_TICK_OUTER_RAD * RADIUS * cosTheta + CENTER.getX());
         int y2 = (int) (LRG_TICK_OUTER_RAD * RADIUS * sinTheta + CENTER.getY());

         g2.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
      }

      g2.setColor(CENTER_HUB_COLOR);

      int x = (int) (CENTER.getX() - CENTER_HUB_RADIUS);
      int y = (int) (CENTER.getY() - CENTER_HUB_RADIUS);
      int width = (int) (2 * CENTER_HUB_RADIUS);
      int height = width;
      g2.fillOval(x, y, width, height);
      // g2.draw(ellipse);

      g2.dispose();
      return img;
   }

   @Override
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      if (backgroundImg != null) {
         g.drawImage(backgroundImg, 0, 0, this);
      }

      Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
      g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

      g.setColor(DIAL_COLOR);
      int x1 = (int) (DIAL_INNER_RAD * RADIUS * cosTheta + CENTER.getX());
      int y1 = (int) (DIAL_INNER_RAD * RADIUS * sinTheta + CENTER.getY());
      int x2 = (int) (DIAL_OUTER_RAD * RADIUS * cosTheta + CENTER.getX());
      int y2 = (int) (DIAL_OUTER_RAD * RADIUS * sinTheta + CENTER.getY());

      g.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);

   }

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      final DailAnimation mainPanel = new DailAnimation();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("DailAnimation");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);

      int delay = 100;
      new Timer(delay, new ActionListener() {
         int speed = 0;

         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            speed ++;
            if (speed > DailAnimation.MAX_SPEED) {
               ((Timer)evt.getSource()).stop();
            }
            mainPanel.setSpeed(speed);
         }
      }).start();
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Im not hardcoding numbers, that was just simplified code. I'm not sure how to get rid of that overriding component paint method.

Comment: @Kamil: you shouldn't get rid of it.

Comment: I mean I dont know how to apply this part of your reply to my code: "override the paintComponent(Graphics g) method of an object that derives from JComponent or one of its children such as JPanel"

Comment: You mean that I should put my lines and shapes on some child component instead of drawing directly on "main window"? I updated my question and added some code.

Comment: I changed "resolution" (MAX_SPEED) to 1024 to get smooth movement, and decreased timer to 1. It expected reaching max value in about 1 second, but it takes a lot more time. It's because java is slow, or I missed something?

Answer (score 0):

Drawing a line via `Graphics.drawLine()` writes pixels directly to whatever is backing the Graphics instance. If you want to rotate the line, you must calculate what its coordinates should be when rotated. This is the only way to draw things in AWT and Swing.

You could write a needle class that maintained its angle, and then have it handle its rendering every frame.

Comment: I can do it, there is no problem, but should I use `Graphics` and clear previously drawed shapes and re-draw them everytime?

Comment: @Kamil: there are some images that will persist -- the dial for instance, which should be drawn in a BufferedImage, and there are parts of the image that will change, the needle for instance, and that could be drawn anew each time.

Comment: Yeah, if you're handling the painting for a form yourself, you'd usually fill it with a rect of the background color, or an image based background, and then draw all the dynamic geometry again. You'll want to make sure that whatever you are drawing on is double buffering, or you'll get a flicker.

Comment: @Kamil: also, you will want to cast your Graphics object to a Graphics2D object and use its `setRenderingHint(...)` method to do anti-aliasing: `g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);`

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I understand that I don't have to redraw static things, like dials etc., I want to focus on animated needle now. Thanks for tip with antialiasing, I will google for RenderingHints and I think its enough for me.